# Doesnt display propertly on iphone se

Tags: iphone, display

I would like to ask a following question. I have designed these web sites, and where I a using your gallery

https://www.tomromaniuk.com/

Everything seems working out, but only when websites is displayed in Appel iPhone se 2015.
When in standing mode- narrow screen- it works perfect when horizontal- ehn i click on image to be loaded and see it bigger, it loads very tiny small picture...

how can I solve that issue please?
thank you

Comment: I looked at the web using emulator in chrome. Obviously you are setting width and height of some elements using `style` (which is a bad practice by itself). Since we have no information how you are doing that, we cannot help.
Please, add relevant code.

Comment: I have done also test. I went online on lightbox gallery website with my iphone, tunr my iphone horizontally and let random picture opened, and it does not open fully. it only shows it very tiny, a stamp size. I think its something that it is inside the lightbox gallery, how can it be fixed pe please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Trying it out online on lightbox gallery sites proved the same. horizontal view on iphone se 2015 seems not working when trying to click on photo- does not come out big on screen, but tiny small